# how do i add a variable to an appended html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
function grid() {
    console.log("Grid loaded");
    var gridHtml = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < gridSize + 1; i++) {
        gridHtml += '<div data-value="var i" class="grid pointer">' + i + "</div>";
        $("#gridContainer").append(gridHtml); //append
    }
}
```

So I append  VARIABLE i  to the document,
how do I make the contents of variable I (in this case it is a number) appear in the data attribute tag?

so basically, I want it like

```
<div data-value="1" class="grid pointer"></div>
<div data-value="2" class="grid pointer"></div>
<div data-value="3" class="grid pointer"></div>
<div data-value="4" class="grid pointer"></div>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

using string concatenation to concatenate the value variable `i` to string leteral, also the string `+=` is not required since you are appending the string inside the loop

```
function grid() {
    console.log("Grid loaded");
    var gridHtml = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < gridSize + 1; i++) {
        gridHtml = '<div data-value="' + i + '" class="grid pointer">' + i + "</div>";
        $("#gridContainer").append(gridHtml); //append
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dZz36/)

Another option is concatenate all the loop string and then append it to the container after the loop is completed

```
function grid() {
    console.log("Grid loaded");
    var gridHtml = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < gridSize + 1; i++) {
        gridHtml += '<div data-value="' + i + '" class="grid pointer">' + i + "</div>";
    }
    $("#gridContainer").append(gridHtml); //append
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UyXVz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
for (var i = 1; i < gridSize+1;i++) {
    gridHtml += '<div data-value="'+ i +'" class="grid pointer">' +i+ '</div>';
    $("#gridContainer").append(gridHtml); //append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gridHtml += '<div data-value='+i+' class="grid pointer">' +i+"</div>";
```

do it like this

Comment: @RoyMJ: That's perfectly valid: `'/*etc*/' +i+"/*etc*/"`